# Why did they rollback to that specific point in The Triangle?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-triangle

I just saw [The Triangle](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0452573/). They explained what happened and it all started in 1943. 
Due to some ship wanted to be invisible.

So at the end of the movie, they destroy the Triangle and everything gets rolled back.

Why were they rolled back to that point in the movie (about a few years ago)?
Why wasn't it rolled back to 1943 when the first disappearance happened and the Bermuda Triangle was created?